# Endogenous omitted variable in the model

Tags: regression, causality, linear, omitted-variable-bias

If I know about an omitted variable in the regression and the data for it is available. But I also know that this omitted variable is endogenous, because the dependent variable and the omitted variable cause each other (simultaneity). Should I include the omitted variable and does that introduce new problems for my variable of interest?

Comment: Is your goal prediction, explanation, or an attempt to find causality?

Comment: Attempt to find causality

Comment: You will have problems in either case, either omitted variables bias when omitting or simultaneity bias when including. If you include it, you can try if you can find an instrumental variable for the endogenous regressor.